# $BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to display an AlertDialog from a coroutine. My AlertDialog function looks like this:

```
fun confirmDialogueBox(context : Context) {

// Late initialize an alert dialog object
lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog
// Initialize a new instance of alert dialog builder object
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AlertBoxTheme))

// Set a title for alert dialog
builder.setTitle("Would you like to Download this Novel")

// On click listener for dialog buttons
val dialogClickListener = DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, which ->
    when (which) {
        DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> Toast.makeText(context, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
        DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE -> Toast.makeText(context, "no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
        DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL -> Toast.makeText(context, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
}

// Set the alert dialog positive/yes button
builder.setPositiveButton("YES", dialogClickListener)

// Set the alert dialog negative/no button
builder.setNegativeButton("NO", dialogClickListener)

// Set the alert dialog neutral/cancel button
builder.setNeutralButton("CANCEL", dialogClickListener)
// Initialize the AlertDialog using builder object

// Finally, display the alert dialog
dialog = builder.create()
dialog.show()    //line 33 as in the error report.
```

}

I am calling this function in the event of a FloatingActionButton click.

```
findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
       
        val currentChapUrl = "https://novell.com/chapter-2.html"  
        val context = applicationContext
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val resFromChapCountFunct = getTotalChapCount(context,currentChapUrl)  //suspend functoin
           
            if(resFromChapCountFunct > 0) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main)   {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "just a toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()   //upto this its working.
                    confirmDialogueBox(context)
                }
            }
            downloadChapters(context,currentChapUrl)  //download chapters from the current chapter number until the last chapter available.
        }
    }
```

After showing the toast message, the app crashes.

The error message is pasted below:

```
2020-08-02 10:28:25.943 4815-4923/com.example.daoreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.daoreader, PID: 4815
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:683)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
    at com.example.daoreader.ConfirmDialogueBoxKt.confirmDialogueBox(confirmDialogueBox.kt:44)
    at com.example.daoreader.WebviewActivity$onCreate$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(WebviewActivity.kt:33)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have searched and tried various solution. None worked so far.Please help.

Comment: have you tried changing `applicationContext` to your current  Activity context?

Comment: could you tell me how to do that. I have only seen Java examples of this so far.

Comment: looks like the way has been shown by @Mohammad Zarei below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It causes error, because it can't find the current view's `context` to show the `AlertDialog`

So what you need to do is replacing `val context = applicationContext` to

```
val context = view.context
```

Comment: With the architecture components the click listener would be a method in the ViewModel. I do not have (and should not pass in) the view there, but only the application via AndroidViewModel.getApplication(). Any solution for that situation? And any explanation,  why it does not work with applicationContext.

Comment: I just tried it. Passing the view.context into the method call of the AndroidViewModel, allows to open a dialog inside the coroutine launched in the view model. Using getApplication() as context of the dialog instead, throws the mentioned Exception. Still strange!?